# Парсинг word (docx)

Tags: xml, ruby, парсер, ms-word

Есть задача, распарсить некое количество docx файлов и разложить их в базе, сами по себе файлы большие, имеют общую структуру, вида:

**Оглавление**

**Текст**

**Некоторые данные вида маркированнного списка**

**Контактная информация**

Попробовал разобраться с xml, но не пойму, за что там можно зацепиться.

Реализовывать буду на **ruby**, посмотрел гемы, но ничего подходящего не нашел, может есть у кого мысли по этому поводу.

Comment: Зачем вдруг на Ruby - это что, онлайновый сервис будет? Или дело просто в том, что не знаете других языков? Тогда попробуйте IronRuby, то есть для .NET, для .NET сразу несколько библиотек есть.

Comment: Да, это будет онлайновый сервис.

Comment: Ну и онлайновый можно сделать под .NET, для этого есть ASP.NET.

Comment: Проект весь будет на рельсах и тут уже ничего не поделать, нужно каким то образом парсить большие docx.

Comment: Для работы с docx есть популярные библиотеки OpenXML и ClosedXML. Думаю, из Ruby их тоже можно использовать.

Comment: Я вам настоятельно рекомендую взять [OpenXML](https://rubygems.org/gems/openxml-docx/versions/0.10.0). DocX - слишком сложный формат, не разбирайте его вручную.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я уже пробую разобрать xml полученный из odt, но не могу понять как получить текст из вложенных тегов, к примеру, телефоны если идут в строчку, то я без проблем их получаю, но если это список, то не получается.

Comment: Тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598260/docx-viewer-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0 я привёл пример парсинга на c#, думаю, на ruby можно переделать. С нумерацией я тоже столкнулся - сделал её на js.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще docx это zip архив, содержащий xml файлы, в соответствии с которыми ворд рендерит весь файл. Вы можете анзипнуть ваш файл, пройтись по нужной xml парсером (в Qt например QXmlReader), вытащить необходимые вам данные и запаковать назад. Чтобы лучше понять структуру docx можете скачать MS Office Open Xml SDK.

Comment: Структуру xml с данными я смотрел и по этому возник вопрос, не пойму как привязаться к тегам в нем.

Comment: В чем собственно сложность? Открываете document.xml из папки word в анзипнутом docx, там все содержимое файла разделенное тегами, ищите нужные теги и читаете с них, тем более, что документы с общей структурой. В руби есть аналог работы с Dom документами, как в Qt QDomDocument?

Comment: Проблема в том, что теги все там одинаковые, только в заголовке отличаются, по тексту очень много списков, которые относятся к разным атрибутам.

Comment: `запаковать назад` – а зачем?

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой пример, для более точного извлечения откройте свой XML и ищите теги которые Вас интересуют, подставляйте вместо "//w:t" или "//w14:checkbox"

```
require 'nokogiri'       
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("document.xml"))
# Тексты, заголовки и т.п.
strings = @doc.xpath("//w:t") 
puts strings
# чебоксы
checkboxes = @doc.xpath("//w14:checkbox") 
puts checkboxes.to_s
```

Comment: А с маркированными списками как быть? Если считать, что код руби выполняется последовательно, то между началом и концом у нас будет несколько таких списков, использовать что то на подобии `text()`? Я никак не могу получить текст заголовка, я пробовал, что то подобное из Вашего примера `zag = @doc.xpath("//w:bookmarkStart//w:r//w:t")`. Так же у меня есть текст, который будет использоваться как атрибут, это в основном в маркированных списках, то же не пойму как сделать.