# Обход объединенных ячеек в Word

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office, office-interop

В общем, в продолжение своей предыдущей темы по парсингу таблиц Word'a с помощью interop я столкнулся с объединенными ячейками.

Как я могу узнать на сколько ячеек произошло объединение, что бы я мог размножить F3 на N строчек?

[image]

Капался в дебаггере в поисках нужного свойства, но что-то не нашел... Да и в интернете поголовно пишут, что такого свойства нет

**UPD 1**

На одном из ресурсов подкинули вот такую идею(Код на VBA, но легко переписывается на C#):

```vb
Sub ParseInExcel()
    Dim doc As Document, tbl As Table, eObj, eWbk, eWst, eRng, eCell
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set doc = ThisDocument
    Set tbl = doc.Tables(1)
    tbl.Range.Copy
    Set eObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set eWbk = eObj.Workbooks.Add
    Set eWst = eWbk.Sheets(1)
    eWst.Paste
    Set eRng = eWst.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
    For i = 1 To eRng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To eRng.Columns.Count
            Set eCell = eRng.Cells(i, j)
            If eCell.MergeCells Then
                Debug.Print eCell.MergeArea.Cells(1).Value & " ";
            Else
                Debug.Print eCell.Value & " ";
            End If
        Next
        Debug.Print
    Next
    eWbk.Saved = True
    eWbk.Close
    Set eWbk = Nothing
    eObj.Quit
    Set eObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Смысл в том, что из Word все копипастится в Excel, а там уже появляются свойства, которые показывают объединение ячеек-`MergeRange`. Проблема в том, что будет занят буфер обмена(самое проблемное на мой взгляд, так как не смогу работать за ПК в момент работы программы иначе покалечу буфер), а так же в том, что подключается второй всадник апокалипсиса-Excel.

Если Excel знает, как представить таблицу из Word и создать свойства, которые показывают, что некая зона объединена, то значит должен иметься какой-то однозначный алгоритм для вычисления этого средствами Word'a.

Даже при сохранении в html-формате пишется кол-во объединенных колонок и строк.

**UPD 2**

По объединенным строкам я нашел решение, но по колонкам нет. Накидал [свое решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/808073/32793), но не думаю, что оно универсально.

Может у кого-то есть еще идеи?

P.S Interop не принципиален, но в приоритете, так как много кода на нем нарисовал.

Если есть решение например для *.DOCX, то я могу сменить формат.

Comment: Обычно таблица с  обьедененными ячеками "видится как" таблица с необьедененными, где пусто в ячейках где произошло "обьединение". Т.е. если в ячейке пусто - она потенциальный кандидат на то что она является частью обьеденённой ячейки. Если вы проводите анализ - этого достаточно (того что есть). Если надо отобразить один в один - тогда прийдётся копать дальше.

Comment: @nick_n_a, да, методом тыка я докопался до этого. Мне бы понять могу ли я какой-нибудь рейндж объединения получить, что бы я знал откуда до куда копировать значения, что бы это разложить в обычную табицу.Например, в строке 4 ячейки, а следом идет строка с 2-мя объедененными ячейками, по идее, это будет видится как 2 ячейки, а мне нужно это представить, как 4 с копированием информации в соседнии.

Comment: Для docx, думаю... могу наверстать. Таблица в документе одна, или много?

Comment: @nick_n_a, много и важно сохранять текст между таблицами, если он есть. В текущей реализации я получаю List<object>, куда я агригирую текст и DataTable в порядке их встречаемости.

Comment: Форматирование опустить можно?

Comment: @nick_n_a, да..

Comment: А требуется... `DataTable` где вместо обьеденённых ячеек null, или требуется список структур типа `{text,x,y,colspan,rowspan}` ?

Comment: Т.е. вычислить позицию, что бы в DataTable позиции столбцов и строк точно соответствовали таблице - можно (проще) или же структуру {text,x,y}. Кстати colspan и rowspan - легко вычислить двумя циклами... Ну а второе делается значительно сложнее

Comment: @nick_n_a, я в своей текущей реализации, просто копировал одно и тоже значение на весь диапазон объединенных ячеек.

Answer (score 2):

Получим xml с docx это не сложно [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/677294/17974)

Давайте рассмотрим такую таблицу

> ```
> 1 4 < 5
> 2 - - ^
> ```

Где < и ^ - направление обьединения ячеек.
Тогда получим следующее (оставляю только значащие теги)

```
<w:document>
 <w:body>
  <w:tbl>
      <w:tr>
         <w:tc>(1)</w:tc>
         <w:tc><w:rcPr><w:gridSpan w:val="2"/></w:rcPr>(4)</w:tc>
         <!-- отсутствует колонка -->
         <w:tc><w:rcPr><w:vMerge w:val="restart"/></w:rcPr>(5)</w:tc>
      </w:tr>
      <w:tr>
         <w:tc>(2)</w:tc>
         <w:tc>-</w:tc>
         <w:tc>-</w:tc>
         <w:tc><w:rcPr><w:vMerge/></w:rcPr></w:tc>
      </w:tr>
```

Текст хранится в тегах `<w:t>текст</w:t>`.  Вычислить обьеденённый столбец этим способом легче - по тегу gridSpan. Обьеденённые строки прийдется перелистывать `vMerge` тег.

Вот пример как получить доступ к тегам внутри docx

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
public class Demo {
 public static void docx2process(Stream file) {
        int isTable = 0; /*Для парсинга xml*/
        int  col = 0;
        int  row = 0;
        int colSpan = 1;
        /*Парсинг архива*/
        int ready = 0; while (ready++ < 10){ /*защита от повисания, обход архива*/
            byte[] head = new byte[30]; file.Read(head, 0, 30); if (head[0] != 'P') break;  //zip-header
            int i = (head[27] + head[29]) * 256 + head[28]; //  extra len
            long paked = BitConverter.ToInt32(head,18);
            byte[] nam = new byte[255];
            file.Read(nam, 0, head[26]);
            if (i != 0) file.Seek(i, SeekOrigin.Current);
            String aname = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(nam, 0, head[26]);
            if (aname == "word/document.xml"){
                long lastpos = file.Position;
                using (System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream deflate = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(file, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)){                        
                    System.Xml.XmlReader rd = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(deflate);
                    // Тут парсинг документа
                    while (rd.Read()){
                       if (rd.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) 
                          switch (rd.Name){
                              case "w:gridSpan":  colSpan = int.Parse(rd.GetAttribute("w:val"));break;
                              case "w:vMerge":; /*Тут нужно допилить обьединение строк*/  break;
                              case "w:tbl": row=0; isTable = rd.Depth ; break;
                              case "w:tr": col=0; row++; break;
                              case "w:tc": col+= colSpan; colSpan=1; break;
                              case "w:t":/*Теги с текстом*/
                                 if (rd.Read() && rd.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                                     /*Тут нужно написать свой вывод куда-либо*/
                                     if (isTable>0) 
                                         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("c={0}.{3} r={1} t={2}",col,row,rd.Value, colSpan)); 
                                      else Console.WriteLine(rd.Value);
                                 break;                                    
                              case "w:p": /*Параграф*/ if (isTable == rd.Depth) isTable = 0; break;
                              }
                       }
                    return;
                }                                        
               file.Position = lastpos + paked;
            }else file.Seek(paked, SeekOrigin.Current);
        };                
       }


   public static void docx2process(string filename) {
        using (Stream f = File.OpenRead(filename))  docx2process(f);
       }

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
       docx2process("1.docx");    
      }
 }
```

этот пример почти решает поставленую задачу. Обьедененные столбцы - видно. Обьеденённые строки - ещё нужно доработать.

Comment: Вы пишете "не сложно" и при этом даете ссылку на портянку кода для работы с XSLT, не относящуюся к теме... Напишите хоть, что в контексте interop эти танцы не нужны и достаточно использовать свойство Range.XML.

Answer (score 1):

Изучение вот этого простого кода

```
Sub test()
Dim oneTable As Table
Dim oneCell As Cell
Dim i As Integer

Set oneTable = ThisDocument.Tables(1)
For Each oneCell In oneTable.Range.Cells
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print i, oneCell.RowIndex, oneCell.ColumnIndex
Next
End Sub
```

на тестовых табличках с объединением ячеек даст достаточно информации для решения проблемы.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Методом тыка я к этому пришел. Однако, не могу найти способа, которым можно было бы высчитать рейндж, что бы понять на сколько строчек все было объединено. Т.е сверху 4 колонки, а снизу 2 объединенные. И мне как-то нужно понять, как разложить правильно 2 в 4.

Comment: *не могу найти способа, которым можно было бы высчитать рейндж, что бы понять на сколько строчек все было объединено* Соответствующий индекс - это индекс правой верхней ячейки. Если в текущей ячейке индекс по какому-то направлению, скажем, 3, а в следующей 6, значит, ячейка 3 объединена с ячейками 4 и 5. Т.е. прямого указания - нет, только вот такое косвенное.

Answer (score 1):

> Даже при сохранении в html-формате пишется кол-во объединенных колонок и строк.

Так может и воспользоваться этой деталью? Перегнать doc в html и распарсить атрибут *colspan*/*rowspan*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//Add Reference: Microsoft HTML Object Library

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static List<string> FindMergedColumns(string html)
        {
            List<string> res = new List<string>();

            mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = null;
            mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 d2 = null;
            mshtml.IHTMLDocument3 d = null;            

            try
            {
                doc = new mshtml.HTMLDocument();
                d2 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)doc;
                d2.write(html);
                d2.close();

                d = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)doc;
                var coll = d.getElementsByTagName("table");
                object val;
                int numtable = 1;
                int row = 1, column = 1;
                int span;

                foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement2 table in coll)
                {
                    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                    foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement2 tr in rows)
                    {               
                        var cells = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");
                        foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement td in cells)
                        {
                            val = td.getAttribute("colspan");
                            if(val == null)val = 0;
                            span = Convert.ToInt32(val);

                            if (span > 1)
                            {
                                res.Add(String.Format("Table {0}, Row {1}, Column {2}: {3} columns merged",numtable,row,column,span));
                            }

                            column++;
                        }
                        row++;
                        column = 1;
                    }
                    numtable++;
                    row = 1; column = 1;
                }
                doc.close();
            }
            finally
            {
                //освобождение ресурсов
                if (doc != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
                if (d2 != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(d2);
                if (d != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(d);
            }
            return res;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] argv)
        {
            var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object path = "c:\\test\\test.doc";
            object readOnly = true;
            var docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly,
                                           ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                           ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                           ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                           ref miss);

            string tmp = Path.GetTempPath() + "file.htm";

            //конвертируем doc в html
            docs.SaveAs(FileName: tmp, FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML);
            ((_Document)docs).Close();
            ((_Application)word).Quit();

            //парсим HTML
            string html = File.ReadAllText(tmp);
            var res = FindMergedColumns(html);
            File.Delete(tmp);

            foreach (var line in res) Console.WriteLine(line);
            Console.ReadKey();            

        }        

    }

}
```

Comment: Можно, но я до последнего хотел найти решение на чистом интеропе.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на строки:

```
 WordTableAnalyser wta = new WordTableAnalyser(table,1.0);
 MyWordCell c = wta.getCell(8, 1);
 MessageBox.Show(c.rows.ToString() + ";" + c.columns.ToString());
```

Исходная таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приложение на основе Windows Forms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WorkWithWord
{
    using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    public class MyWordCell
    {
        public double x = 0;
        public double x2 = 0;
        public double w = 0;
        public int columns = 1;
        public int rows = 1;
        public int ini_row=-1;
        public int ini_column=-1;
        public Word.Cell wc;
        public MyWordCell(Word.Cell cell)
        {
            wc = cell;
        }
    }
    public class DoubleToleranceComparer : IComparer<double>,IEqualityComparer<double>
    {
        double tolerance=0;
        public DoubleToleranceComparer(double tolerance)
        {
            this.tolerance = tolerance;
        }
        #region Члены IComparer<double>

        public int Compare(double x, double y)
        {
            double delta = x - y;
            return Math.Abs(delta) <= tolerance ? 0 : Math.Sign(delta);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Члены IEqualityComparer<double>

        public bool Equals(double x, double y)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int GetHashCode(double obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
    public class WordTableAnalyser
    {


        public static Object missingObj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        public static Object trueObj = true;
        public static Object falseObj = false;

        Word.Table wtable = null;
        double cc = 0;//количество необъединенных столбцов
        double rc = 0;//количество необъединенных строк
        double WT = 0;//ширина таблицы
        double HT = 0;//высота таблицы

        DoubleToleranceComparer dt_comparer;//сравниватель double c допуском

        SortedList<double,double> split_xs;//встречающиеся  координаты границ ячеек таблицы по x



        List<MyWordCell> curRow = new List<MyWordCell>();
        List<List<MyWordCell>> myTable = new List<List<MyWordCell>>();


        public MyWordCell getCell(int ini_row,int ini_column)
        {
            MyWordCell c = null;


            for (int ci = 0; ci < myTable[ini_row-1].Count; ++ci)
                {
                    if (myTable[ini_row - 1][ci].ini_column == ini_column)
                    {
                        c = myTable[ini_row - 1][ci];
                        break;
                    }
                }


                return c;
        }

        public WordTableAnalyser(Word.Table table,double tolerance)
        {
            wtable = table;
            cc = table.Columns.Count;
            rc = table.Rows.Count;
            dt_comparer = new DoubleToleranceComparer(tolerance);
            split_xs = new SortedList<double,double>(dt_comparer);
            split_xs.Add(0.0, 0.0);
            for (int i = 1; i <= cc; ++i)
            {
                try
                {
                    Word.Cell cell=table.Cell(1,i);
                    MyWordCell myCell = new MyWordCell(cell);
                    myCell.x = WT;
                    myCell.w = cell.PreferredWidth;
                    myCell.x2 = myCell.x + myCell.w;
                    myCell.ini_row = 1;
                    myCell.ini_column = i;
                    curRow.Add(myCell);
                    WT += cell.PreferredWidth;//Width не всегда определена

                    //cell.
                    split_xs.Add(WT, WT);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                { 

                }
            }
            myTable.Add(curRow);

            for(int j=2;j<=rc;++j)
            {
                List<MyWordCell> prevRow = curRow;
                curRow = new List<MyWordCell>();
                List<MyWordCell> myTableRow = new List<MyWordCell>();
                int prevColInd = 0;
                double curX=0;
                for (int i = 1; i <= cc; ++i)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Word.Cell cell=table.Cell(j,i);
                        MyWordCell myCell = new MyWordCell(cell);
                        myCell.x = curX;
                        myCell.w = cell.PreferredWidth;
                        myCell.x2 = myCell.x + myCell.w;
                        myCell.ini_row = j;
                        myCell.ini_column = i;
                        curRow.Add(myCell);
                        //while(myTable.Count<myCell.in)
                        myTableRow.Add(myCell);
                        //cell.
                        try
                        {
                            split_xs.Add(myCell.x2, myCell.x2);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) { }
                        curX = myCell.x2;
                        if (dt_comparer.Compare(myCell.x, prevRow[prevColInd].x) == 0)
                        {
                            while ((prevColInd<prevRow.Count) && (dt_comparer.Compare(prevRow[prevColInd].x, myCell.x2) < 0))
                            prevColInd++;
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)//для текущего ряда по данному индексу пропуск
                    {
                        if (prevColInd < prevRow.Count)
                        {
                            prevRow[prevColInd].rows++;
                            curRow.Add(prevRow[prevColInd]);
                            curX = prevRow[prevColInd].x2;
                            prevColInd++;
                           }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                myTable.Add(myTableRow);
            }

            //добавляем недостающие колонки
            for (int j = 0; j < myTable.Count; ++j)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < myTable[j].Count; ++i)
                {
                    MyWordCell c = myTable[j][i];
                    double x = c.x;
                    double x2 = c.x2;
                    int ind_x=split_xs.IndexOfKey(x);
                    int ind_x2 = split_xs.IndexOfKey(x2);
                    int delta_ind=ind_x2 - ind_x;
                    if (delta_ind > 1) c.columns += delta_ind - 1; 
                }
            }


        }
    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static Object missingObj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        public static Object trueObj = true;
        public static Object falseObj = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Word._Application application;
            Word._Document document=null;

            //создаем обьект приложения word
            application = new Word.Application();
            // создаем путь к файлу
            Object templatePathObj = @"D:\Work\Life\StackOverflow\Разбиение объединённых ячеек в таблице.docm"; ;

            // если вылетим не этом этапе, приложение останется открытым
            try
            {
                document = application.Documents.Add(ref  templatePathObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);

                Word.Table table = document.Tables[1];//в файле примера одна единственная таблица
                int rcount = table.Rows.Count;
                int ccount = table.Columns.Count;


                WordTableAnalyser wta = new WordTableAnalyser(table,1.0);
                MyWordCell c = wta.getCell(8, 1);
                MessageBox.Show(c.rows.ToString() + ";" + c.columns.ToString());

                application.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                if(document!=null)document.Close(ref falseObj, ref  missingObj, ref missingObj);
                application.Quit(ref missingObj, ref  missingObj, ref missingObj);
                document = null;
                application = null;
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Суть в том, что ты делаешь выводы об объединении ячейки на основании ширины и высоты некого эталона?

Comment: Ширина у ячеек есть. Ширина таблицы получается из ширин первой строки. Максимальное разбиение таблицы на строки и столбцы можно получить. Далее для каждой строки рабочая строка строится на основе предыдущей. Если в текущей строке нельзя получить ячейку по индексу, то берётся ячейка из предыдущей строки и у неё увеличивается cчётчик rows и обновляется по ней текущая координата x для строки. Все уникальные начала и концы строк по x с некоторым допуском выстраиваются в split_xs.  У ячеек запоминаются кординаты x начала и конца. В заключении, увеличивается rows, если между концами есть в split_xs

Comment: Высоты в алгоритме не участвуют.

Comment: ЧИТАТЬ В заключении, увеличивается columns, если между координатами х концов есть в split_xs значения.

Answer (score 0):

Поиски привели меня на [сайт](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/GetRowColSpan.htm), где я нашел такое решение для определения объеденных строчек:

```
int GetRowSpan(Cell cell)
{
    cell.Select();
    return (int)_wordApp.Selection.Information[WdInformation.wdEndOfRangeRowNumber] - (int)_wordApp.Selection.Information[WdInformation.wdStartOfRangeRowNumber] + 1;
}
```

К сожалению, ничего подобного я не нашел для объеденных колонок...

Написал свое решение, но не думаю, что оно универсальное:

```
int GetColumnSpan(WordTable table, Cell cell)
    {
        var columnIndex = cell.ColumnIndex;
        var etalonSize = table.Cell(1, columnIndex).Width;
        if (cell.Width - etalonSize < 0.5)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        var curWidth = cell.Width;
        var mergCount = 1;
        while (curWidth - etalonSize > 0.5)
        {
            curWidth -= etalonSize;
            mergCount++;
        }
        return mergCount;
    }
```

Суть в том, что на вход я подаю эталонную ширину ячейки, а затем сравниваю ее с текущей. Если ширина болье => ячейка объеденена...

Если у кого-то есть мысли лучше, то пишите.

Answer (score 0):

```
Если ТипФайла = "Word" Тогда
    
    Попытка             
        Соединение = ПоключитьсяКWord(ПутьКФайлу);
        Если Соединение = Неопределено Тогда
            Возврат;
        КонецЕсли;
        
        //Открываем и активируем документ Word      
        //Док = ПолучитьCOMОбъект(ПутьКФайлу); 
        Word = Соединение.Application.Documents(1);
        Таблица = Word.Content.Tables(1);
        
        ТекущаяСтрока = 1;
        ТекущийСтолбец = 1;
        
        Пока ТекущаяСтрока <= Таблица.Rows.Count Цикл
            Пока ТекущийСтолбец <= Таблица.Columns.Count Цикл
                Если ТекущийСтолбец = 1 И ТекущийСтолбец <= Таблица.Columns.Count Тогда
                    Попытка
                        П1 = Таблица.Cell(ТекущаяСтрока, 1).Range.Text;
                    Исключение
                        П1 = "";
                    КонецПопытки;
                КонецЕсли;
                Если ТекущийСтолбец = 2 И ТекущийСтолбец <= Таблица.Columns.Count Тогда
                    Попытка
                        П2 = Таблица.Cell(ТекущаяСтрока, 2).Range.Text;
                    Исключение
                        П2 = "";
                    КонецПопытки;    
                КонецЕсли;
                Если ТекущийСтолбец = 3 И ТекущийСтолбец <= Таблица.Columns.Count Тогда
                    Попытка
                        П3 = Таблица.Cell(ТекущаяСтрока, 3).Range.Text;
                    Исключение
                        П3 = "";
                    КонецПопытки; 
                КонецЕсли;
                Если ТекущийСтолбец = 4 И ТекущийСтолбец <= Таблица.Columns.Count Тогда
                    Попытка
                        П4 = Таблица.Cell(ТекущаяСтрока, 4).Range.Text;
                    Исключение
                        П4 = "";
                    КонецПопытки;
                КонецЕсли;
                Если ТекущийСтолбец = 5 И ТекущийСтолбец <= Таблица.Columns.Count Тогда
                    Попытка
                        П5 = Таблица.Cell(ТекущаяСтрока, 5).Range.Text;
                    Исключение
                        П5 = "";
                    КонецПопытки;
                КонецЕсли;
                Если ТекущийСтолбец = 6 И ТекущийСтолбец <= Таблица.Columns.Count Тогда
                    Попытка
                        П6 = Таблица.Cell(ТекущаяСтрока, 6).Range.Text;
                    Исключение
                        П6 = "";
                    КонецПопытки;
                КонецЕсли;
                Если ТекущийСтолбец = 7 И ТекущийСтолбец <= Таблица.Columns.Count Тогда
                    Попытка
                        П7 = Таблица.Cell(ТекущаяСтрока, 7).Range.Text;
                    Исключение
                        П7 = "";
                    КонецПопытки;
                КонецЕсли;
                Если ТекущийСтолбец = 8 И ТекущийСтолбец <= Таблица.Columns.Count Тогда
                    Попытка
                        П8 = Таблица.Cell(ТекущаяСтрока, 8).Range.Text;
                    Исключение
                        П8 = "";
                    КонецПопытки;
                КонецЕсли;
                Если ТекущийСтолбец = 9 И ТекущийСтолбец <= Таблица.Columns.Count Тогда
                    Попытка
                        П9 = Таблица.Cell(ТекущаяСтрока, 9).Range.Text;
                    Исключение
                        П9 = "";
                    КонецПопытки;
                КонецЕсли;
                Если ТекущийСтолбец = 10 И ТекущийСтолбец <= Таблица.Columns.Count Тогда
                    Попытка
                        П10 = Таблица.Cell(ТекущаяСтрока, 10).Range.Text;
                    Исключение
                        П10 = "";
                    КонецПопытки;
                КонецЕсли;
                Если ТекущийСтолбец = 11 И ТекущийСтолбец <= Таблица.Columns.Count Тогда
                    Попытка
                        П11 = Таблица.Cell(ТекущаяСтрока, 11).Range.Text;
                    Исключение
                        П11 = "";
                    КонецПопытки;
                КонецЕсли;  
                Если ТекущийСтолбец = 12 И ТекущийСтолбец <= Таблица.Columns.Count Тогда
                    Попытка
                        П12 = Таблица.Cell(ТекущаяСтрока, 12).Range.Text;
                    Исключение
                        П12 = "";
                    КонецПопытки;
                КонецЕсли;
                
                ТекущийСтолбец = ТекущийСтолбец + 1;  
            КонецЦикла;         
            ТекущаяСтрока = ТекущаяСтрока + 1;
            ТекущийСтолбец = 1;
            
            НоваяСтрока = Описание.Добавить();
            НоваяСтрока.П1  = СокрЛП(П1);
            НоваяСтрока.П2  = СокрЛП(П2);
            НоваяСтрока.П3  = СокрЛП(П3);
            НоваяСтрока.П4  = СокрЛП(П4);
            НоваяСтрока.П5  = СокрЛП(П5);
            НоваяСтрока.П6  = СокрЛП(П6);
            НоваяСтрока.П7  = СокрЛП(П7);
            НоваяСтрока.П8  = СокрЛП(П8); 
            НоваяСтрока.П9  = СокрЛП(П9);  
            НоваяСтрока.П10 = СокрЛП(П10);  
            НоваяСтрока.П11 = СокрЛП(П11);
            НоваяСтрока.П12 = СокрЛП(П12);
            
            П1  = "";
            П2  = "";
            П3  = "";
            П4  = "";
            П5  = "";
            П6  = "";
            П7  = "";
            П8  = "";  
            П9  = "";  
            П10 = "";  
            П11 = "";  
            П11 = "";
            
        КонецЦикла;
        
        // Закрытие Word и освобождение памяти
        ОтключатьсяОтWord(Соединение); 
        
    Исключение
        //Отключится в случае ошибки
        ОтключатьсяОтWord(Соединение); 
    КонецПопытки;
    
КонецЕсли;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
...
for (int row = 3; row <= table.Rows.Count; row++)
 {                     
    cell = table.Cell(row, 1); // первая ячейка
    k1 = cell.Range.Text; 
   try
     {
      TheMerge = 0;
      cell = table.Cell(row, 2); // Если 2 существует значит не мерге
      }
     catch (Exception)
     {
       //что-то делаем если объединённая
       TheMerge = 1;
       }

      if (TheMerge == 0)
         {  
         //что-то делаем если не объединённая
           }
}
```